# How to get the total number of partitions in Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm trying to set split file names by a pattern but I don't know how to get the total number of partitions.

The name I'm looking for the files is `my_file_name_pattern_[n]of[N].txt`

The partitions are getting set dynamically by a key column.

[image]

How can I get `[N]`?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I got an answer from Microsoft:

> We are adding a new "cached lookup" feature to AzDF that builds upon the existing Lookup/Sink transformation where for example we can access the output from an aggregation and use that value in another transformation in the dataflow.

**Update!**

Now we can set values in a dataflow without the need of using sink to load a file in Blob store and using extra activities to read it. Check `Cached lookup` documentation:

[Cache Sink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-sink#cache-sink)
[Cached lookup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-data-flow-expression-builder#cached-lookup)

In the `Sink` we can select `Cache` instead of Dataset...

[image]

Then we can use that value in any of the other activities:

like `mySinkName#outputs()[myRowNumber].yColumnName`

[image]

**workaround before Cached lookup**

While this new feature is released. I got an approach using `As data in column` opt instead of `Pattern` to name the files, here the solution:

In the data flow I have two sources:

- **Source1**: get the number of partitions from a calculation. The output will be in a `Select` transformation with one value:

```
    | partitions |
    |      3     |
```

[image]

- **Source2**:

  1. connect to a table (`Synapse/Hive`) you want to split in multiple files
  2. add a `Surrogate Key` transformation starting at `1`, column name `SK`

[image]

3. add an `Union` transformation and use `Custom (cross)` join, in condition use `true()`

[image]

4. add a `Derived column` to get the key column to split the files `partition_number` = `mod(SK, partitions) + 1`

[image]

5. add another `Derived column` to get the column `files names` = `concat($target_folder, '/', $fileName, '_', toString(partition_number), 'of', toString(partitions), '.', $extension)`

[image]

5.1. in `Optimize` use `partition_number` column in the option `Key`

[image]

6. add a `Sink` to `ADLS` and in the `setting` tab set `As data in column` and use `file_name` column for `Column with file name`

[image]

6.1. in `Mapping` tab use `rule-based mapping` to ignore the temp columns created in the flow.
- Input Columns: `!in(['SK','partition_number','partitions','file_names'], name)`
- Output Columns: `$$`

[image]

> **Note:** At work we have a custom AzDF and some of the activities are locked or disable for us. That's why this workaround instead of using `SP` and `Lookup` at the pipeline level. Also I don't like the idea of saving some data in ADLS in any delimited format and then use it with a lookup activity to extract the value and set some parameter... It seems over steps for a simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated**
You need two dataflow activities and one Lookup activity to achieve this.

[image]

1. This is the preview of dataflow4. It's purpose is to get the Total number(21).

[image]

2. In the Aggregate1, we define the Group by and Aggregates to group by the **partition column**

[image]
[image]

3. In the SurrogateKey1 activity, we can generate the **Row_No** for the rows.

[image]

4. In the Aggregate2 activity, we can use `max(row_count)` to get the max value of the **Row_No**.

[image]

5. We set the sink to store the Total Num(21) to a csv file.

[image]

6. Use the Lookup1 activity to lookup the file which dataflow4 generated previously.

[image]

7. In the dataflow3, we can define a parameter **Total** and use pipeline expression `@activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow.Prop_0` to get the total num.

[image]

8. In the sink of dataflow3, we can use `concat('Loan_payments_data[n]of',$Total)` to define the filename after partition.

[image]

9. Then after we run debug, the result is as follows:

[image]

Comment: I know that. The think is, I want that value in the file name. Something like: `loan_payments_data_1of21, loan_payments_data_2of21, loan_payments_data_3of21, ..., loan_payments_data_21of21`.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to solve this. I'm trying to avoid extra activities. I already had some approaches with lockup and parameters but they seems like a big work around for something simple. I think DF must have a simple option like the `[n]` option they already have. If you look at the json output of the last activity and scroll down there is a property with the number of partitions used. The value is already there. Ideally dataflow should have a way of set variables to use later in the same dataflow.